# object build in comparison Object.is()

Tags: javascript, object, comparison

```
  let obj = {
  one : 1 , 
  two : 1 , 
  three : 1 , 
}


function recursiveCheckEqual(x , ...rest){
  return Object.is(x , rest[0]) && (rest.length < 2 || recursiveCheckEqual(...rest));
}

recursiveCheckEqual(1 , obj). //  why return single "false"
```

it was an  object's value comparison of more than two value . However I can't wrap my head around this ,   how does this actually work ?
1 . how does it achieve recursive ?
2 . does "return" return whole argument ( object--to --- rest ) ;

Comment: "*how does it achieve recursive ?*" because it recursively calls itself with `recursiveCheckEqual(...rest)`

Comment: @VLAZ , but why the computed result is false? recursiveCheckEqual(1 , obj)  => single line false

Comment: Because `1` is not equal to `obj`. With two arguments all `recursiveCheckEqual(1 , obj)`  would do is execute `Object.is(1, obj)` and it won't even recursively call itself. A number is not equal to an object, so it returns `false`.